# Ideas de como validar fechas y horas agendadas mediante solo input

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

para explicarme mejor estoy realizando un proyecto escolar en conjunto(en equipo), el proyecto es un sistema de gestión de citas en el campo de consultorio dental. En el cual actualmente estoy estancado ya que no sé como proceder a validar las citas, por ejemplo, agregar una fecha y una hora de la cita y si esta ya está registrada, que lance un mensaje de "Esta fecha ya esta agendada, ingrese otra por favor", será de mucha ayuda que me dieran consejos o tips ya que es mi primera vez haciendo esto, actualmente estamos usando Php y Mysql, se los agredecería mucho.

Si no me explique bien por favor de comentarlo. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un select y solo hacer una consulta con la fecha que te a dado en el formulario ejemplo:

```
$fecha = "23 Sep 2018"; //ejemplo
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM citas WHERE fecha='".$fecha."'";
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 1){
  echo "la fecha ya esta en la agenda";
}else{
  //tu codigo
}
```

Comment: En fecha estaría incluyendo la hora de la cita? o solamente el dia?

Comment: bueno pues según sea tu necesidad

Comment: en tal caso como seria con hora? realmente me es dificil

Comment: Bueno mira lo que puedes hacer es recoger la hora y la fecha(día, mes año, lo que ocupes) del formulario y juntar lo en una sola variable y así podrás ver con el código de arriba si ya esta o si no pues que agregue la cita a la base de datos.

Comment: ok gracias compañero

Comment: mmm, solo para confirmar, para declarar puedo hacerlo asi, por ejemplo,         $cita=$_POST['fecha,hora'];

Comment: juntando dentro los corchete el id del input de fecha y el id del input de hora

Comment: creo que no se puede lo que puedes hacer es poner cada uno en variables diferentes y despues concatenarlos así: $cita = $fecha . $hora . $mes, etc

Comment: okok muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses el plugin datetimepicker te dejo en link para que revises la documentación: [datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Este plugin te va permitir capturar de forma mas sencilla la fecha y hora de la cita.

Otra recomendación es al momento de crear la tabla, como buena práctica tienes que agregar un indice único para la fecha de la cita, ya que esta no debe repetirse, te dejo un ejemplo en MySQL del create:

```
CREATE TABLE `cita` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `user_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `fecha` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `fecha` (`fecha`)
)
```

En esta línea se agrega el indice único:

```
UNIQUE INDEX `fecha` (`fecha`)
```

Comment: Creo que me sirve de mucho, sabes si se encuentra en bootstrap 4?

Comment: Si, te dejo el link  https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/

Comment: mmm, tal vez no me sirva ya que tengo una validación en el cual dice "No puedes ingresar una fecha anterior al dia de hoy" y la verdad no manejo muy bien el javascript para hacer algo como fecha minima o maxima, espero me entiendas